# Building and running VS2005 project on linux with MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I have a VS2005 project that I'm trying to run on linux. First - is it even possible? The project is .NET 2.0, and I have mono JIT 2.0.1 on my linux machine. The project builds successfully in monodevelop, but when I run it I get the exception stack:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.

at System.Data.DataViewManager.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator () [0x00000]

at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemType(System.Object dataSource, System.String dataMember) [0x00000]

at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemType(System.Object list) [0x00000]

at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.SetList (IList I) [0x00000]
```

...

Am I missing some assemblies, or am I just looking for something that can't be done? I don't do that much .NET programming as it is, so please excuse my lack of knowledge on this one.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that method is implemented in newer versions of Mono.  (2.0 is about a year old.)

If you want to scan your assemblies with [MoMA](http://mono-project.com/MoMA), it will tell you which methods you use that Mono does not support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find mono is (or at least used to be) a bit spotty on things like grids and dataviews and datagrids.

Update to the latest mono and tell us if it works!

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time updating to the latest build (2.4.3, I think). Part of it is because my dev machine is on a closed intranet in my company. I'll keep updating on this post if anything new comes up.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, you can try using NTLMAPS, it works pretty well.  http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/